# Перевод кода с VB.NET на C#.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

У меня открыта `Form2`, и при нажатии на кнопку изменялся текст `Label1` на `Form1`

```
Form1.Label1.Text = "Привет"
```

Вот не могу перевести. Переведите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще практически никаких отличий не будет. В целом то, что вы делаете, выглядит так

Первая форма

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    private Form2 f = new Form2();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        f.NotifyParent += new Form2.NotifyParentEventHandler(SetFromForm2);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        f.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void SetFromForm2(string text) {
        label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Вторая форма

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public delegate void NotifyParentEventHandler(string text);
    public event NotifyParentEventHandler NotifyParent;

    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (NotifyParent != null)
            NotifyParent(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого... на VB намного проще 1 строка а тут... 0_О

Comment: А есть простой вариант, в 1 или 2 строчки?

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж [community](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) поднял вопрос:

Более точный аналог кода на C# для тех же условий (у `label1` в дизайнере выставлено Modifiers: public и обе формы открыты):

```cs
((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]).label1.Text = "Привет";
```

Но в реальном приложении так лучше не делать - вместо прямого изменения значений контролов в другой форме лучше использовать события или какой-то из вариантов databinding-а.